# How can FCM incoming messages be reconciled with CN1$AndroidPendingNotifications format?

Tags: codenameone

I tried to implement FCM on a CN1 app. This can be done to an extent, but it then breaks CN1's Google SignIn and potentially other `com.google.android.gms` dependencies as FireBase depends itself on that and there seems to be a version incompatibility (this is what I understood from reading the build logs and from testing)

Then, I decided to feed FCM messages into CN1 (directly from Firebase, not from CN1 servers) and let CN1's own service process these.

This works, but I haven't managed to correctly format my FCM messages to be accepted by CN1. As a result, notifications are shown correctly, but `push(String value)` gives a `null` value. I however have managed to do this in APN, an example of an accepted APN message (CN1 Type 4) can be seen below. All is good when it comes to implementing CN1 APN Push with Apple (suprisingly). All of CN1's client app functionality can be re-used if you just adapt your payload to its [demands](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/080b05a8be5abc17f7c00d0a13c797294c1d8be9/Ports/iOSPort/nativeSources/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m#L409)

```
{
"aps": {
    "alert": {
        "title": "Visible Title",
        "body": "Visible Body"
    },
    "badge" : 1,
    "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
},
"meta":"Hidden message (can be JSON)",
}
```

Looking at CN1's native Android push implementation, I can see that incoming push notifications are stored in a file called `CN1$AndroidPendingNotifications`. Where they go into the file is not clear, I suspect it must be from an ad-hoc service, but so far I haven't found the exact place in CN1's publicly available GitHub repository

The content's format of this file seems to be very specific. For example, its first byte seems to denote an integer with the pending push count, the next byte holds a boolean that tells you whether it has a type, etc. This can be seen [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/080b05a8be5abc17f7c00d0a13c797294c1d8be9/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java#L834)

An FCM message that semi-works (with null push() value) can be seen below

```
        "{"+
            "'message':{" +
                "'token':'" +deviceId+"',"+
                "'notification':{"+
                    "'title':'"+title+"',"+
                    "'body':'"+msgBody+"'"+
                "}"+
            "}"+
        "}";
```

The above results in CN1 Type 1 notification with an empty message(notification is still shown correctly in OS though).

My question is, is there a place in CN1 where the actual FCM message is consumed and massaged into the `CN1$AndroidPendingNotifications` file's format? This would be great to know as it would help me understand the format I have to adapt my incoming FCM notifications, given that implementing FCM separately doesn't play nice with CN1's existing FCM/GMS dependencies

Thanks!

btw: before someone says it, Parse4CN1 only implements iOS push, not FCM :)